# Bring process to screen

Tags: redhat

I am running a process which will take several hours. I would like to disconnect from the server, but I do not want to lose the output to the screen. Is there a way to bring the process back to my screen after I disconnect? It's a Python script that is running, and it is on Red Hat 6.3

Comment: You can do that with `screen`, `tmux` or the classic combination of `nohup`ing it and redirecting the output to a file. Plenty of answer about all of those on [su].

Comment: Any feedback as to why my question was downvoted?

Comment: Not my downvote, but I am *guessing* insufficient research.

Comment: Nor my downvote...but just googling your own title to your question the first 2 results are StackExchange sites with the answer: https://www.google.com/search?q=Bring+process+to+screen

Comment: None of the answer I found speak to how to pull a background process to screen if you didnt use the screen command when launching the command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go back in time and smack yourself for not thinking ahead.

Then, fire up gdb against the running program, break into it and re-open STDOUT against a file. Then you should be able to background and nohup it without losing output.

```
(gdb) attach 18456
Attaching to process 18456
...
(gdb) call open("/tmp/myoutput.txt", 0102)
$1 = 3
(gdb) call dup2(3,1)
$2 = 1
(gdb) call close(3)
$3 = 0
(gdb) detach 
Detaching from program: /usr/bin/python2.7, process 18456
(gdb) quit
```

Then you can <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>, `bg`, and `disown` the original process.

Comment: @Sugitime All of the answers you found implicitly answer your question (***"You can't go back in time."*** - usually). This answer offers you one option, and there are some OS-specific tricks you can do to attach to a different TTY (e.g. [`watch`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=watch) on FreeBSD, but I'm not sure what the Linux/RedHat equivalent is, if one exists.

Comment: You can't go back in time, but you can rewrite history. :D

Comment: That works for me. The answer is you can't do what I want to do, but I can restart the script and do what I want to do if I start it a certain way. Thanks guys.

Comment: "I do not want to lose the output to the screen" <- I even got that for you. :D